# TypeError: object is not a function showing at express

Tags: node.js

Today I am learning Nodejs (Beginner) and execute CURD operation with mysql. I am working with http://teknosains.com/i/simple-crud-nodejs-mysql . Everything working  fine but as last when I am running app.js, I am getting this type of error:

```
baltech@baltech121:/var/www/html/myapp$ nodejs app.js

/var/www/html/myapp/app.js:10
var app = express();

var app = express();
      ^
TypeError: object is not a function

at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/myapp/app.js:10:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
```

What do I do in this case?
My app.js is here

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
//load customers route
var customers = require('./routes/customers'); 
var app = express();
var connection  = require('express-myconnection'); 
var mysql = require('mysql');
// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4300);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}
/*------------------------------------------
    connection peer, register as middleware
    type koneksi : single,pool and request 
-------------------------------------------*/
app.use(

    connection(mysql,{

        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password : 'admin',
        port : 3306, //port mysql
        database:'nodejs'
    },'request')
);//route index, hello world
app.get('/', routes.index);//route customer list
app.get('/customers', customers.list);//route add customer, get n post
app.get('/customers/add', customers.add);
app.post('/customers/add', customers.save);//route delete customer
app.get('/customers/delete/:id', customers.delete_customer);//edit customer route , get n post
app.get('/customers/edit/:id', customers.edit); 
app.post('/customers/edit/:id',customers.save_edit);
app.use(app.router);
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: It seems that you don't have `express` installed in your project. Just run a `npm install express`.

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros You can view my directory structure /app.js  /nbproject  /node_modules  package.json  /public  /routes  /views express is already install

Comment: What is your `express` version? What's the result of running `npm ls express` from your project root folder?

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros When i am running above command on root getting express@4.12.3  but in project folder this one is different have express@2.5.8

Comment: That's it: the express version on your project is `< 3.x.x`. Before `3.x.x`, your express app should've been instantiated with `express.createServer()`. From `3.x.x` to now, you just have to do `express()` to get the same result. So, just update the express version on your `package.json` and run `npm install` in your project root folder again.

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros Can u provide me some guideline what i do and How ?

Comment: In your project you have a `package.json` file. Just update the line where you have something like `"express" : "~2.x.x"` to something like `"express" : "^4.0.0"`, which is current stable version, and then run `npm install` on your project root folder.

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros I do as per your guide but now i am getting "Error: Most middleware (like logger) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
    at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (/var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:89:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/myapp/app.js:18:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    
"

Comment: That's expected. `express` v4 included some breaking changes to minor versions, because it decoupled some middleware like `logger` (now `morgan`) and `body-parser`. Just follow the link provided on the error message, which will give you the information you need to refactor your code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have the wrong express version. You can only create the server with express() in v3.x.x. Before this version, express can not be called as a Function.

You can create server using

```
var app = express.createServer();
```

Comment: Some example with explanation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in the order of the require statements - require('http') should come first.