# Node.js Express: TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I run the following code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I get the following error:

```
/var/www/html/test.me/public_html/giftcard/index.js:1
rts, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var app = require('express')();
                                                                           ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/test.me/public_html/giftcard/index.js:1:91)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

What does this error mean? Is the path to express incorrect? I have one directory with `packages.json`, `index.js` (the file above), and `node_modules`, and I have express installed. Where is the error coming from?

Comment: Which version of express did you install? The error indicates that you installed express 3 (the newest version is 4).

Comment: It is most certainly a duplicate to [TypeError: object is not a function showing at express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29209210) if the OP can confirm that the installed express version is `3.x`

Comment: @t.niese I can confirm that I have version 4.16.4 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);`
```

while you can do like this :

```
var app = new require('express')();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

However, your code works perfectly on my node.js .

```
var app = new require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3000')
});
```

Comment: I'm using it so I can pass an `http` object to socket.io when I later implement it, but before I do that I have to sort out my issue above.

Answer (score 0):

The error should be at this line:

`var http = require('http').Server(app);`

For what you are trying to do, you simply need `express` without `http`

```
const app = require('express')();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening on 3000'));
```

If you want to use also `http`, try using this syntax:

```
const app = require('express')();
const server  = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I understand. However, I'm using it so I can pass an http object to socket.io when I later implement it, but before I do that I have to sort out my issue above. I can't use express to begin with.

Comment: so try this: `const app = require('express')();
const server  = require('http').createServer(app);`

Answer (score 0):

Because I used the `nodejs` module on Ubuntu 14.04 to install Node.js, I had an outdated version. I used `nvm` to install the most recent version of Node.js to resolve the errors.